# Finagle using load balancing across custom Services

Tags: java, scala, finagle

Unfortunately all documentation on Finagle only shows examples of using ClientBuilders to build clients.

If I have a Set of Services, is it possible to add load balancing and fail-fast capabilities to it and combine them in one Service this way?

I want something like this:

```
Set<Service<A, B>> serviceSet = ...;
Service<A, B> = Balancer.make(serviceSet);
```

How exactly do I use finagle.loadbalancer and ServiceFactories to do this?